# Fix vertical panning

Tags: stabilisation

I have a video i want to loop (about 6  seconds long) that gradually moves downwards. Which video tool or filter can I use to realign the image?

I experimented with Davinci resolve but it the panning/stabilizing tool has no option to limit it to vertical only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you found a solution, but to set the record straight, DaVinci's stabilization tool can limit its effect to a single axis.  Here are steps which work on as of version 15.2.1:

- Open the color tab.
- Activate the tracker panel (it looks like a crosshairs reticle)
- Change the tracker's mode from window to stabilize.  Do this by clicking on the dropdown disclosure triangle next to the word "Window" or on the word itself.  (this UI behavior is inconsistent in other parts of DaVinci).
- Change the Stabilizer mode to "Classic Stabilizer."  This option exists under the ellipsis dots menu just to the right of the word "Stabilizer."  It's the second item from the bottom of the list.
- You should now see boxes for Pan, Tilt, Zoom, and Rotate.  What you call "vertical pan" is usually called, "tilt" in the industry, so make sure that's the only box that's checked.
- At the bottom of the tracker interface, change the dropdown menu from "Point Tracker" to "Cloud Tracker" if necessary.
- Click "Stabilize."  Additional settings and options are described in the Chapter 119 of the user manual, "Sizing and Image Stabilization."  DaVinci's manual is pretty unwieldy, so it's easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a panning / zoom plugin I found for virtualdub

Comment: Please add details of your solution, so future readers are helped. Thanks.